# Determine points where a LineString meets the boundaries of a Polygon using Turf.js

Tags: geojson, linestring, turf

Using Turf, I'm trying to determine the points at which a line (LineString) meets the boundaries of a polygon.

Turf has the ability to do point-in-polygon/point-on-line and polygon intersections etc, but I can't figure out a way to get Turf to give the answer to the question **"what are the points at which this LineString meets the boundaries of this Polygon"**.

The only options I've come up with so far is to enumerate the points of the polygon as line-segments and then use a line intersection algorithm.  I just hoped there was a more "Turf" way of doing it.

PS - I already asked this over on stackoverflow but someone suggested I try here on gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: I had a look at Turf before, it mainly deals with point-polygon spatial relationships. Provided you are processing "boundaries of a polygon", which basically implies that the relationship should be in between line strings and I think what you are doing is the only way, i.e., converting polygon to line strings, with Turf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, turfjs does not seem to have an API for doing this.

I was able to get the answer I wanted by enumerating the points in the polygon from the GeoJSON object to construct a sequence of line segments and then I used [maxogden/geojson-js-utils](https://github.com/maxogden/geojson-js-utils%20maxogden/geojson-js-utils) `linesIntersect` function to test for intersection points.

PS - this is a copy of the answer from the main stackoverflow question I posted

Comment: The link doesn't exist